# 'bundle' command returns a parsing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle

Command 'bundle' into rails application returns this error:

```
'[!] There was an error parsing 'Gemfile': You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements. You specified: sdoc (~> 0.4.0) and sdoc (>= 0). BUndlr cannot continue.
from c:/Users/MacKenzie/Documents/Programming/Projects/odot/Gemfile:16
------------------------------------
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem

> gem 'tzinfo-data' platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby}
source 'https://rubygems.org'
-------------------------------------'
```

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile?  One common way to get this error is, as stated in the error description, to have the same Gem listed twice...

Comment: The Gem was listed twice, removing one fixed the error, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't include your Gemfile, but I see there is a missing comma before "platforms". There is also a `}` which should be `]`.

An example gemfile, with the mentioned fixes:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```